# Unable to Copy UDF from POLine (PO301000) to POReceiptLine(PO302000) on "Enter PO Receipt" Action

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have created 2 UDF's in POLine and POReceiptLine, I am trying to copy values of those UDF's from POLine to POReceiptLine on "Enter PO Receipt" action in PO Screen(PO301000). My code is getting executed but the values are not getting copied. Please suggest, Thanks

```
protected void POReceipt_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistingEventArgs e)
    {
      
      var row = (POReceipt)e.Row;

            POReceiptLine row1 = new POReceiptLine();
            if (Base.Document.Current != null)
            {
                foreach (POReceiptLine tran in Base.transactions.Select())
                {
                    POLine xPOLine = PXSelect<POLine,
                        Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<POLine.orderNbr>>,
                        And<POLine.orderType, Equal<Current<POLine.orderType>>>>>.Select(Base, tran.PONbr, tran.POType);
                    if (xPOLine != null)
                    {
                        POLineExt poLineExt = PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(xPOLine);
                        POReceiptLineExt poReceiptLineExt = PXCache<POReceiptLine>.GetExtension<POReceiptLineExt>(row1);

                        poReceiptLineExt.UsrWarrantyTerms = poLineExt.UsrWarrantyTerms;
                        poReceiptLineExt.UsrVendorWarrantyDate = poLineExt.UsrVendorWarrantyDate;
                    }
                    return;
                }

            }


        }
```

####...Section 2..####### I have tried using this below code as well but No Luck.

```
 protected virtual void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<POReceiptLineExt.usrWarrantyTerms> e)
        {
            POReceiptLine row = (POReceiptLine)e.Row;
            if (row != null)
            {
                POReceiptLineExt receiptLineExt = row.GetExtension<POReceiptLineExt>();
                POLine line = SelectFrom<POLine>
                    .Where<POLine.pONbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>
                    .And<POLine.lineNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>>
                    .View.Select(Base, row.PONbr, row.POLineNbr);
                POLineExt lineExt = line.GetExtension<POLineExt>();
                if (lineExt?.UsrWarrantyTerms != null && receiptLineExt != null)
                {
                    e.NewValue = receiptLineExt.UsrWarrantyTerms;
                }
            }
        }
        protected void POReceiptLine_ReceiptNbr_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = (POReceiptLine)e.Row;
            if (row == null) return;
            cache.SetDefaultExt<POReceiptLineExt.usrWarrantyTerms>(row);
        }
```

Comment: Have you tryed:  Base.SetValueExt(viewName,Data/row,Value)

Comment: Dear JvD, May I request you be more specific on your feedback, where exactly shall i use the SetValueExt in my code. Actually I am not sure where I need to use the SetValueExt for mu UDF's. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your version, so I'll answer per version 2020R2 that I am running.

Observations:
You seem to be returning after the 1st POReceiptLine in the transactions view.  More importantly, the placement would seem more appropriate on the POReceiptLine_RowPersisting event where you would not have to do the foreach within the RowPersisting.  Lastly, off the top of my head, I can't recall if you need to update the cache when doing this in row persisting if you are working on the record being persisted, but you are working on a different record meaning you likely need to update the cache which gets tricky inside RowPersisting events.  (For example, you may not know if the other cache was already persisted.)

Flow of the action:
POOrderEntry contains the action *CreatePOReceipt* which, in turn, initializes POReceiptEntry and creates the receipt from the order via *CreateReceiptFrom(...)* which then calls *AddPOLine(...)*.  Subsequently, the POReceiptLine is created via *line = this.transactions.Insert(line);*.

Recommendation:
In 2020R2, it seems your code belongs in POReceiptEntry, but you did not specify where you are putting it.  If you placed it in POOrderEntry, the event never fires.

Try putting something like this in POReceiptEntry (do similar for the other field also).

```
protected virtual void _(Events.FieldDefaulting<POReceiptLineExt.UsrWarrantyTerms> e)
{
    POReceiptLine row = (POReceiptLine) e.Row;
    if(row != null)
    {
        POReceiptLineExt receiptLineExt = row.GetExtension<POReceiptLineExt>();
        POLine line = SelectFrom<POLine>
            .Where<POLine.pONbr.IsEqual<@P.AsString>
            .And<POLine.lineNbr.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>>
            .View.Select(Base, row.PONbr, row.POLineNbr);
        POLineExt lineExt = line.GetExtension<POLineExt>();
        if(lineExt?.UsrWarrantyTerms != null && receiptLineExt != null)
        {
            e.NewValue = receiptLineExt.UsrWarrantyTerms;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the PONbr and LineNbr fields may not be set yet, you may need to use SetDefaultExt for those 2 fields at the appropriate place.  (I'd suggest maybe trying in the POReceiptLine.POLineNbr FieldUpdated event.)  I believe the insert from the action coming from POOrderEntry already has the fields filled in, but that may not be the case in every way the POReceiptLine record is created, so you want to be sure you are setting the values EVERY time that it is warranted.

Comment: Dear Brian, I am using 2020 R2, I have tried suggestion given by you, But I found mere any luck. Request you to please check the question, i have made some edits in the question as per your suggestion, if anything went wrong, please let us know, I will do it accordingly. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution to this issue i.e. by using field level event and calling the function from a field level event, the below code is working perfectly fine for me. Thanks.

```
protected void POReceiptLine_POLineNbr_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var row = (POReceiptLine)e.Row;
            CarryForwardFromPO(row);

        }

        public void CarryForwardFromPO(POReceiptLine row)
        {
            if (row.PONbr == null || row.POType == null || row.POLineNbr == null)
                return;
            POReceiptLineExt _polext = PXCache<POReceiptLine>.GetExtension<POReceiptLineExt>(row);

            if (row.PONbr != null)
            {
                POLine xPOLine = PXSelect<POLine,
                            Where<POLine.orderNbr, Equal<Required<POLine.orderNbr>>,
                            And<POLine.orderType, Equal<Required<POLine.orderType>>,
                            And<POLine.lineNbr, Equal<Required<POLine.lineNbr>>>>>>.Select(Base, row.PONbr, row.POType, row.POLineNbr);

                if (xPOLine != null)
                {
                    POLineExt xPOLineExt = PXCache<POLine>.GetExtension<POLineExt>(xPOLine);
                    if (xPOLineExt != null)
                    {
                        if (xPOLineExt.UsrVendWarrantyType != null)
                        {
                            _polext.UsrVendWarrantyType = xPOLineExt.UsrVendWarrantyType.Trim();
                        }

                        if (xPOLineExt.UsrWarrantyTerms != null)
                        {
                            _polext.UsrWarrantyTerms = xPOLineExt.UsrWarrantyTerms.Trim();
                        }
                        if (xPOLineExt.UsrVendorWarrantyDate != null)
                        {
                            _polext.UsrVendorWarrantyDate = xPOLineExt.UsrVendorWarrantyDate;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```